# Создание LINQ запроса выборки между датами (SQLite)

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, linq

```
 var dateToDate = db.DateSet.Where(p => p.Date >= calendarStart.SelectedDate && p.Date >= calendarEnd.SelectedDate);


    class Day 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Drink_id { get; set; }
        public String Date { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

Так как в SQLite нет типа для даты, юзаю текст, как построить LINQ запрос beetwen между дататами  из календаря если тип даты String

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то DateTime поддерживает EF, который сам из строки переведет все в нужный формат.

Comment: Поддержу @EvgeniyZ. Вам надо изменить тип у свойства `Date` на `DateTime`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ругается  "The 'Date' property on 'Day' could not be set to a 'System.String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.DateTime'. "    Хотя в базе date not null

Comment: Попробуйте `DateTime?` тип

Comment: @EvgeniyZ безрезультатно

Comment: Ну тогда у вас что-то очень странное, ибо `DateTime?` - тип, который позволяет содержать NULL. Другой вариант, задать какое либо значение по умолчанию в базе. В любом случае, эта поддержка вроде как есть и вам надо бы разобраться что не так. По поводу вопроса, делайте тогда костыли - `p.Date` меняйте например на `DateTime.Parse(p.Date)`, но это сами понимаете - костыль.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я бы не хотел костылей строить, по этой причине задал вопрос,может подскажете куда глядеть куда копать? хочу разобраться

Comment: Не, я вам тут не помогу, увы, с базами не особо дружу. Советую вам задать вопрос по этой ошибке, описав подробно что вы делаете и как, может кто поможет. Тут конечно может и я что путаю, но вроде когда работал со SQLite (EF), проблем с датой не было, единственное что было - это когда я неверно писал дату в базу сам, руками. Очистил базу, через EF добавил данные, он мне сам задал нужный формат, по которому я потом руками и добавлял все остальное. Вот кстати [таблица](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTngu.png), а вот [данные](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS7Ji.png). Попробуйте может тоже формат проверить

Comment: @EvgeniyZ А в итоге помогли ) заработало ) формат был неверным